# Passing value between ngModel

Tags: c#, angular, angular-components, angular-ngmodel

item-list.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="selectedItem">
    <h2>Product Details</h2>
    <div>ID: {{ selectedItem.id }}</div>
    <div>
      Name:
      <input
        type="text"
        ngModel="{{ addCartRequest.name ===selectedItem.name}"
        disabled
      />
    </div>
</div>
```

item-list.component.ts

```
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[]=[];
  selectedItem?: Product;

  addCartRequest: Cart= {
    id: '',
    name: '',
    quantity: 0,
    totalPrice: 0
  }
constructor(private productsService: ProductsService,private cartService: CartsService, private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.productsService.getAllProducts()
    .subscribe({
      next: (products)=>{
        this.products = products;
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }

  onSelect(item:Product):void{
    this.selectedItem=item;
  }

  addCart(addCartRequest:Cart){
    this.cartService.addCart(this.addCartRequest).subscribe({
      next: (cart)=> {
        this.router.navigate(['customer/cartDetails'])
      }
    });
  }

}
```

I'm trying to pass value from **selected-item.name** to **addCartRequest.name** in item-list.component. Angular newbie here. The system is about a checkout system where users select items to checkout. I'm letting users select items, but I can't put them in the cart as a disabled input. Not sure if there is another way. If I put **ngmodel** as **selectedItem.name**, the value won't be sent to the cart as **addCartRequest.name**. I just want to show users what they have selected and send the value to the cart. How do I send the value of other ngmodel to other ngmodel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input that is always disabled should be a paragraph. There's not point in using an input.

But for your question :

```html
<input
    type="text"
    [ngModel]="selectedItem.name"
    disabled
/>
```

That's all you need. To update your request :

```js
onSelect(item:Product):void{
    this.selectedItem=item;
    this.addCartRequest.name = item.name;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I have thought about not using it as input but I just want to return the selectedItem.name into addCartRequest.name. From all tutorials I have watched, they are providing value to ngmodel as input. Your answer work to show the user what have they selected. But I can't proceed to send the value into addCartRequest object

Comment: @MuhammadArif update my answer

Comment: No problem, be sure to upvote if it helped, and to mark as resolved if it answered all your questions !